# Creating a table in vuetify with v-data-iterator passing an object from an api

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, data-conversion

After a full day of searching and testing, here I am. I first tried to do a simple Row with 2 columns table and iterate on the object to fill the left column with the it's keys, but couldn't find how to do the same with the value of the keys for the second column. I then found out the existance of v-data-iterator which does exactly just that! But then as the title implies, I get an error since I'm feeding it an object instead of an array. I get that! But I tried many work-arounds with no avail, like this example where wherever I put it I get an error of some sort:

```
const exception= { producer: 'John', director: 'Jane', assistant: 'Peter' }; //my obj
const arr = Object.entries(exception); //my obj in array
```

Here is an example of an object my api returns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar11w.png
At this point I'm pretty sure that I'm simply missing a little something somewhere... Here is my actual (non working) code:

````
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-data-iterator :items="exception" hide-default-footer>
        <template v-slot:header>
          <v-toolbar class="mb-2" color="indigo darken-5" dark flat>
            <v-toolbar-title>{{ exception.exceptionName }}</v-toolbar-title>
          </v-toolbar>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:default="props">
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              v-for="item in props.items"
              :key="item.exceptionName"
              cols="12"
              sm="6"
              md="4"
              lg="3"
            >
              <v-card>
                <v-card-title class="subheading font-weight-bold">
                  {{ exception.exceptionName }}
                </v-card-title>

                <v-divider></v-divider>

                <v-list dense>
                  <v-list-item>
                    <v-list-item-content>Calories:</v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-content class="align-end">
                      {{ item.exceptionId }}
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </v-list-item>

                      ... Other keys and values

                </v-list>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </template>
      </v-data-iterator>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "UniqueException",
  data() {
    return {
      exception: [], //the object
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    Axios.get("https://localhost:7121/api/exceptions/" + this.$route.params.id)
      .then((answ) => {
        this.exception = answ.data; //copy of the api object and pastes it in the object "exception"
        console.log(answ.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>```
````

Comment: `I put it I get an error of some sort` ... that's not helpful ... what is the error?

Comment: As you said, Your API returns an object but in your code you are assigning the object in an array. Can you please confirm, what is `answ.data` returning ? An `array of objects` or a single `object` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX If it is in the template section I simply get no data, if it is alone in the script section, it dosent see the exception object, when I put it in the data section (still in the scrypt section) It tells me that const is an unexpected keyword and arr an unresolved variable and if in the mounted exception is still not defined in there

Comment: @RohìtJíndal it is a single object which as the form visible in the print screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert that object into an array of objects like so

```js
const exception= { producer: 'John', director: 'Jane', assistant: 'Peter' }; //my obj
const asArray = Object.entries(exception).map(([position, name]) => ({position, name}));
console.log(asArray);
```

Now you have an array of Objects in the form `{position, name}`

Comment: As they say, a good night of sleep does wonder and I figured out where to put that snippet of code... In my case, I had to replace `this.exception = answ.data;` 

by 

`this.exception = Object.entries(answ.data).map(([position, name]) => ({
          position,
          name,}));`

I still have some problems to fix but it is now an accepted array!